# How to Improve quality in Fiz?

Tags: fiz

I dump all of my craft points into quality(31), and still can't peek over 1100 at best plus all of my equipment is at its max level.

For reference, I'm doing challenges 3&4 for pride of the city

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your employees' attributes determine how often and how much quality is added during the brew. It sounds like you have a lot of Craft points, but what are your employees' critical attributes for their roles in the brew?

The game checks a particular attribute or set of attributes of each employee when brewing to determine *how often* quality is added. **Cleaning** uses the employee's Patience Attribute, **Mashing and Boiling** uses Intelligence and Dexterity, **Fermenting** uses Intelligence and Patience, and **Packaging** uses Dexterity.

Beyond that, the sum of an employee's total attributes determines *how much* quality to add each time quality is added. Which means it is important to have high stats overall, not just the ones for a particular job.

With that in mind, if you're still using employees from earlier in the game, they have limited potential because of their low base attributes and the level 10 cap. Hire employees from later in the game, even if their level 1 attributes are a slight downgrade from your early level 10 employees. They'll soon outperform the early game employees after they level a few times, and they typically have better special abilities.

Comment: So I need to equally focus on their core attributes while also not ignoring craft?

Comment: @BadTimingPlays Yes. Craft offers you more adaptability from brew to brew — e.g. you can use the points to improve Yield in one brew, and Quality in the next — but the core attributes contribute to Quality alone, and more so than Craft.